# About the set of adherence values of a sequence $\bigcap_{n=1} cl\{x_n,x_{n+1},...\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

With the set of adherence values of a sequence $(x_n)$ is equal to $\bigcap_{n=1} cl\{x_n,x_{n+1},...\}$
I found difficult to answer the question 4 of this exercise

Let $\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology, $(x_n)_n$ a real sequence and $f :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ a continuous and bounded function.

1 Give the definition of The set of adherence values  $U$ of a sequence $(x_n)_n$ .

2 Give an example of a sequence for which  $U$ est non vide.

3 Give an example of a sequence for which $U$ is nonempty.

4 Let $(v_n)_n$ a sequence with the following general term $v_n = f(x_n)$ et $V$ its set of adherence values.

a Show that $V \neq \emptyset$.

b Show that $f(U)\subset V$.

c Suppose that the sequence $(x_n)_n$ is bounded. Show that $f(U) = V$ .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: One answer to 1. is $\{x \in X\mid \forall O \in \mathcal{U}(x): \forall m \in \Bbb N: \exists n\in \Bbb N: n \ge m \land x_n \in O\}$. 2 and 3 are identical questions and 4 makes no sense.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks. Why the questions 4 makes no sense.

Comment: The $u_n$ come out of nowhere and the sentence following it is ungrammatical.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I edit the question $x_n$ in place of $u_n$

Comment: 4a is trivial as the image is bounded. 4b follows from continuity.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks I got 4b and I correct the question 4c. I try to understand 4a  but I couldn't, can you help me with detail plz.

Comment: In a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R$ every sequence has an adherence point. Heine-Borel…

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks you very much